# Display column name with data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to display column name for their respective data.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM <Tablename> WHERE domain_name='google.com'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($row) ; $i++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo mysql_field_name($row,$i); // its not working.
    echo $row[$i]."<br/>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Please help.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_` with `mysqli_` : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php

Comment: are you use mysql or mysqli ??

Comment: mysqli_field_name() doesn't work. Could you please help?
I'm kind of new to php

Comment: @EhsanIlahi I want to use mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fetch_field_direct`:

```
for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($row) ; $i++) { 
   ...
   $finfo = $result->fetch_field_direct($i);
   echo $finfo->name;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row[0]."<br/>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Above code is working. check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to fetch the column names.

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM mytesttable WHERE username="as"';
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);
```

You will get `output as json response`.In future this may help,if you need to output in `json format`.
Thanks, Hope this helps for others.